# Removing Specific HTML Tags with CFML

Tags: regex, coldfusion, html-parsing, cfml, lucee

I need a regex to remove all instances of `<FONT>` and any properties it might have inside it, like `<FONT size=2 face=Verdana>` and its closing tag `</FONT>`. the string i get back, the font tag can contain any property and different variations of values for those properties, and the html structure is not consistent. this is one example of what i get as a string:

```
<UL>
    <LI><FONT size=2 face=Verdana>random text<STRONG>random text</STRONG>random text<SPAN style="LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 11pt; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA"><SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;</SPAN>random text</SPAN> </FONT></LI>
    <LI><FONT size=2 face=Verdana><FONT size=2 face=Verdana><STRONG>random text</STRONG></FONT></LI> <LI>random text</FONT></LI>
    <LI><FONT size=2 face=Verdana>random text</FONT></LI>
    <LI><FONT size=2 face=Verdana>random text</FONT></LI>
```

and this is what i would like it to look like after using the regex:

```
<UL>
    <LI>random text<STRONG>random text</STRONG>random text<SPAN style="LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 11pt; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA"><SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;</SPAN>random text</SPAN></LI>
    <LI><STRONG>random text</STRONG></LI>
    <LI>random text</LI>
    <LI>random text</LI>
    <LI>random text</LI>
```

I have tried different variations and I've been able to remove the `<FONT` part but not its properties, the ending `>`, or the closing tag `</FONT>`

This an example of what I'm using

```
loc.result = rereplace(arguments.htmlString, "\\<FONT[^*\\>", "", "ALL");
```

I apologize for my bad regex code, so any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is why you shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9534819). Having said that, Try `(?:<FONT[^>]*>|<\/FONT>)`. See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sSH66W/1)

Comment: I am not trying to parse an html, im just trying to remove those font tags.

Comment: Put your html into an XML object and use XPath. Much more reliable than using regex. The regex will break the first time you run into html that has text in the html that is example code showing how to use the font tag (inside a <pre> or <code> tag for example).

Comment: @SamM Are you *really* going to trust that the HTML is valid XML too?

Comment: @JamesAMohler You're right but one can always hope. I guess I wouldn't hold my breath though on the html being valid xml if the html is so old as to still use the font tag. ;)

Answer (score 5):

As written by others before, don't use REGEX for that.  Use an HTML parser like JSoup.

[Download the JSoup jar file](https://jsoup.org/download) and save it somewhere on your classpath, and then use the following function (cfscript syntax, tested with [Lucee](http://lucee.org/), but should work with any CFML engine):

```
<cfscript>
/** removes the given tag from the input html while keeping its contents */ 
function removeTag(input, tagname){

    var Jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
    var doc   = Jsoup.parse(arguments.input);
    var body  = doc.body().child(0);
    var tags  = body.select(arguments.tagname);

    for (var tag in tags){
        for (var attr in tag.attributes().asList())
            tag.removeAttr(attr.getKey());
    }

    var result = body.toString();
    result = replace(result, "<#arguments.tagname#>",  "", "all");
    result = replace(result, "</#arguments.tagname#>", "", "all");

    return result;
}
</cfscript>
```

Then just call the function with the HTML code that you want to clean, e.g.:

```
cleanHtml = removeTag(inputHtml, "font");
```

To test your example, I added the following:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="input">
<UL>
    <LI><FONT size=2 face=Verdana>random text 1<STRONG>random text 2</STRONG>random text 3<SPAN style="LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 11pt; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA"><SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;</SPAN>random text 4</SPAN> </FONT></LI>
    <LI><FONT size=2 face=Verdana><FONT size=2 face=Verdana><STRONG>random text 5</STRONG></FONT></LI> <LI>random text 5</FONT></LI>
    <LI><FONT size=2 face=Verdana>random text 6</FONT></LI>
    <LI><FONT size=2 face=Verdana>random text 7</FONT></LI>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfdump var="#{ output: removeTag(input, "font"), input: input }#">
```

And the output is as follows:

[image]

I recommend also reading my blog post [Harnessing the Power of Java in CFML](http://blog.rasia.io/blog/harnessing-the-power-of-java-in-cfml.html)

Comment: Not enough jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Regex can be made like so: `<\/?FONT.*?>` ([test and example](https://regex101.com/r/ke2EK2/2)).

But overall **do not use regex for HTML/XML parsing**. Here's why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2610466

**UPDATE**: Fixed answer as per better undestanding of the question